# Automapper return the proxy object instead of string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

We used automapper in MVC5 project and it's working as expected on local server, but after we published it to production server, automapper sometimes return a proxy object instead string till we restart the application from IIS.

We tried to figure out the cause of the problem but did not get the reason.

Do you have any idea?

Display:

```
System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Company
```

Instead of company name.

Comment: If it's an older AM version you should upgrade.

Comment: version 4.2.1.0